# Does chrome have a timeout for connected web sockets that have not sent a message in some time?

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome, time, websocket

This is a problem, i have discovered in a system i am working on, i just want to know if chrome closes connections that does not send messages within a certain period of time. If so then i can fix it, i would just like to know how long does chrome give before it closes such a connection. I have look through chrome settings to see if there is anything it could tell me.
[this is what i see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWzEY.png) on the python server there is no error it just states that the websocket has closed.

Comment: Yes, chrome will timeout a WebSocket connection if no data is passed between the client and server, generally, the common approach here is to have a ping pong type system in place or a heartbeat from the server side that just sends an empty message every x number of seconds

Comment: does the amount of messages from the client effect this timer?

Comment: not as far as I know, it's based on an interval since the last message was sent/recieved. As to what the exact number of seconds is, I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks very much

Comment: No worries, I've posted an answer below, just so you can close the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, chrome will timeout a WebSocket connection if no data is passed between the client and server, generally, the common approach here is to have a ping-pong type system in place or a heartbeat from the server side that just sends an empty message every x number of seconds.

It is based on an interval since the last message was sent/received, which after some research appears to be approximately 10 seconds in chrome, but may vary for different browsers and/or server configuration.

Comment: I haven't located the exact interval (the search is what brought me here!) but the interval is currently (December 2018) significantly longer than 10 seconds. It's in the order of minutes, if not hours. I wonder if it's actually the server side timing it out, which is why you experienced 10 seconds (your server is more aggressive about closing websockets than mine).

Comment: @GregPettit could you please point me to your source?

Comment: @TonyVlcek Per my comment, I actually don't have a source, and posited that it might have been the server timing out. I observed a timeout, and therefore my source is simply anecdotal evidence, which isn't strong evidence at all. I wouldn't blame you if you simply didn't believe it. That would be fine. ;-) Lennart's 10 seconds being different from mine supports the hypothesis that it was regulated by server side.